# Running a rails app with Jruby in 1.9 mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

Been trying to run a rails app using terminal in jruby 1.9 mode. I tried the following, but ran into a series of errors:

```
$ jruby --1.9 script/rails s
LoadError: load error: /Users/aaronmcleod/Documents/sojourner/config/boot -- java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jruby.RubyObject cannot be cast to org.jruby.RubyException
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
  require at /Users/aaronmcleod/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29
   (root) at script/rails:5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the new YAML parser which has some internal bugs. Check your yaml files, for any symbols, you have to replace them with strings. In my case it was:

```
--- a/config/locales/de.yml
+++ b/config/locales/de.yml
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@ de:
     abbr_day_names: [So, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa]
     month_names: [~, Januar, Februar, März, April, Mai, Juni, Juli, August, September, Oktober, November, Dezember]
     abbr_month_names: [~, Jan, Feb, Mär, Apr, Mai, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Okt, Nov, Dez]
-    order: [ :day, :month, :year ]
+    order: [ "day", "month", "year" ]

   time:
     formats:
```

See also the related bug report: [JRUBY-5802](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5802)

You can determine the faulty yaml file by iterating over all files and try to parse them:

```
jruby --1.9 -ryaml -e 'ARGV.each {|file| puts file; YAML.load_file(file) }'  $(find . -name '*.yml')
```

Comment: It's probably one of the devise language yml files. As they have various special characters for all the translations.

Comment: iterate over all of them and try to parse them, i'm going to update the answer.

Comment: Gave that a shot: jruby --1.9 -ryaml -e 'ARGV.each {|file| puts file; YAML.load_file(file) }'  $(find . -name '*.yml')
./.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml
./.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml
RubyException$i$0$2$initialize.gen:65535:in `call': java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jruby.RubyObject cannot be cast to org.jruby.RubyException
 from CachingCallSite.java:242:in `cacheAndCall'

Comment: try to avoid searching in the .gem folder, just check your own code. The last printed filename is the one that causes the problems

Comment: Sorry about that, didnt realize i was in ~ :(. Anyways, it's the cucumber.yml file that sits in the config directory. I've tried wrapping some content as strings, but still no luck. https://gist.github.com/980806 here is my yml file

Comment: ah, damn, thats a erb/yaml, meaning it gets 'changed' before it is parsed again. Can you remove (temporarily) it to see if that is causing the problem?